# Does the ubuntu upgrade 20.04LTS to 22.04.01LTS handle LUKS + LVM?

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, encryption, lvm, luks

I saw that 22.04.01LTS is out and I am excited since I really want the new kernel! https://ubuntu.com/blog/upgrade-your-desktop-ubuntu-22-04-lts

However, from my understanding there have been problems with systems like mine running LUKS + LVM (if this is the correct term?). I tried changing the kernel when installing the system but had troubles being locked out of the system, unable to boot.

I have encrypted my drive when installing 20.04 according to this guide:
https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-enable-full-disk-encryption-on-an-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Are problems like "sda3_crypt: cryptsetup failed after 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade" fixed now?
[sda3_crypt: cryptsetup failed after 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403753/sda3-crypt-cryptsetup-failed-after-20-04-to-22-04-upgrade)

Is it safe to upgrade even for systems running LUKS + LVM, like mine?

Have anyone successfully upgraded from 20.04LTS to 22.04.01 on a system with LVM + LUKS?

Kind regards
K

Comment: Did you end up upgrading 20.04 to 22.04? i also do have my disk encrypted

Comment: Hi MatayoshiMariano!
No - I have not yet had the guts to try it since I depend heavily on my computer. :/

Comment: So... I ended up not upgrading my distro. I just bought a new SSD, installed 22.04 from scratch, copied over my /home directory and spent 24 hours reinstalling all applications. Worked nice though, since almost all settings were preserved. TIP: Make note of what packages and versions you have installed! I had a lot of trouble with firebase-tools. /K

Comment: I probably have same problem when upgrading from 22.04.2 to 22.04.3