# Encrypted disk not available in boot process after distro upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, encryption, luks, btrfs

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu 20.04 following [this guide](https://mutschler.dev/linux/ubuntu-btrfs-20-04/) with btrfs-luks encryption.

The boot process used to involve only a single passphrase prompt at the very beginning.

Today, after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, booting fails.

I still receive a passphrase prompt at the very beginning of the boot process. But now I am receiving the following output (all UUIDs modified for clarity):

```
Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Begin: Waiting for root file system ... Begin Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Midding modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

After this output, it drops me into a (initramfs) prompt.

Running `cat /proc/cmdline` gives me:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/@/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ro rootflags=subvol=@
```

Listing disks by uuid via `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` gives me (again, UUIDs are replaced for clarity):

```
aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa -> ../../nvem0n1p2
bbb-bbb-bbb-bbb-bbb -> ../../nvem0n1p3
ccc-ccc -> ../../nvme0n1p1
ddd-ddd-ddd-ddd-ddd -> ../../nvme0n1p4
```

So, the UUID mentioned is not available.

If I decrypt manually using `cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 cryptdata` (and entering the passphrase again) I receive:

```
BTRFS: device fsid=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx devid 1 transid 797369 /dev/dm-0 scanned by systemd-udevd (527)
```

When I now run `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`, the missing uuid is now included:

```
aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa -> ../../nvem0n1p2
bbb-bbb-bbb-bbb-bbb -> ../../nvem0n1p3
ccc-ccc -> ../../nvme0n1p1
ddd-ddd-ddd-ddd-ddd -> ../../nvme0n1p4
xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx -> ../../dm-0
```

When I now `exit`, the boot process continues running without problem.

Now I am looking for a way to have the boot process run by itself again. I suspect that some config file might have been overwritten during the upgrade, and I think in addition to the installation guide linked above some adjustments have been necessary, but I do not remember exactly.

What I have tried:

- Booting from a USB stick, decrypting and mounting manually, chroot into the mount, and running `update-initramfs` as suggested by answers to similar questions. No effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution turned out to be:

```
echo "KEYFILE_PATTERN=/etc/luks/*.keyfile" >> /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook

update-initramfs -c -k all
```

It seems like the conf-hook was overwritten by the update. After restoring the KEYFILE_PATTERN, and running update-initramfs, it is working as intended again.

Comment: Should I do this before or after upgrading?

Comment: Assuming your setup is similar to mine (following the tutorial linked in the question) you have already done this. The trick is to keep the file intact. During the update I was prompted for several files to keep or overwrite with default. I assume this was one of them. If you keep it, it should be fine.

Comment: In my case it was the same file, but I had to set ASKPASS=y

Comment: I ran into this issue and it was unrelated to a distro upgrade.  I was trying to convert my install from "regular" to "encrypted" in-place using a different guide, and I was not able to boot after I was done.  This turned out to be exactly the step that was missing, and after updating the conf-hook file, everything is good now.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon another possible fix, not sure if it is applicable for your setup though.

[sda3_crypt: cryptsetup failed after 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403753/sda3-crypt-cryptsetup-failed-after-20-04-to-22-04-upgrade)

> I've performed exactly the same steps to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04
> and ran into the very same issue. I have no idea what is the cause of
> it yet I was able to work around it by decrypting the partition using
> the old passphrase by booting from ubuntu live usb and adding a new
> one.
>
> ```
> Boot from the ubuntu live usb.
>
> I've used the 22.04 from the official downloads page.
>
> Using the UI I've unlocked the partition. 
>   - just try open the disk from file manager
>
> Determine which partition is the encrypted one. 
>   the partition UUID is stored on the /etc/crypttab relative to your drive. 
>   For example cat /media/GUID/ubuntu/etc/crypttab. 
>
> Then use blkid | grep PARTITION_GUID <- change the guid to determine the partition name. 
>
> In my case it was /dev/nvme0n1p3
>
> Add a new additional passphrase sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey 
>   /dev/nvme0n1p3 <- change the partition name.
>
> You will be prompted twice for a new passphrase.
>
> Reboot into your primary os
> ```
>
> The old passphrase was still not working but the new one did the
> trick.
>
> It is very likely that there is a more optimal way to achieve this but
> this one worked for me :p

Answer (score 0):

The same error can happen if for any reason the package `cryptsetup-initramfs` has been deleted. This utility adds the `cryptsetup` command to the initramfs BusyBox shell.

To install it again:

```
sudo apt install cryptsetup-initramfs
```

If the initramfs image is not updated you can do it manually using

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k <your-kernel-version>
```