# Is there any discernable changes on modified LUKS system files that are checkable for changes before reboot?

Tags: encryption, luks, testing, passphrase

**UBUNTU 20.04LTS LUKS PASSPHRASE FAIL**

UBUNTU 20.04 LTS (FULL DISC ENCRYPTION) INITIAL SITUATION:

Upon rebooting my 20.04 LTS the LUKS passphrase was not accepted, with these messages.

- reboot ….
- please unlock disc sda3_crypt
- 3x cryptsetup failed, bad password or options ?
- volume group “vgubuntu” not found
- cannot proceed volume group vgubuntu
- done.
- …
- missing modules (cat proc modules: ls /dev)
- ALERT!  /dev/mapper/vgunbuntu-root does not exist
- Dropping to shell
- BusyBox V1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4 ubuntu6.4) builtin shell (ash)
- (initramfs)_

"I only ever added one LUKS password and have never modified any LUKS settings.
Unfortunately I didn’t complete the planned backup in prep of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS upgrade.
I’m reading the following, but I’m still not confident about the GRUB, BUSYBOX, LUKS and INITRAMFS commands."
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/Troubleshooing
[sda3_crypt: cryptsetup failed after 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403753/sda3-crypt-cryptsetup-failed-after-20-04-to-22-04-upgrade)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1979159

**UBUNTU 22.04 USB LIVE SYSTEM COMMAND RESULTS
ON UBUNTU 20.04 LUKS FULL ENCRYPTED DRIVE:**

-lsblk -> sda has

- sda1 8:1 0 512M 0 part -  sda2 8:2 0 732M 0 part - sda3 8:3 0 231.7G 0 part
- gparted → ‘/dev/sda1 ! EFI SYSTEM PARTITION  fat32 512.00MB   boot,esp
- ```
        ‘/dev/sda2                         ext4  732.00MB 209.70MB 522/30MB
  ```
- ```
        ‘/dev/sda3                   [Encrypted]  231.67GiB 231.67GiB 0.00B
  ```
- disks  → Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB, disk is OK, GUID Partition Table
- ```
    ‘/dev/sda1 EFI system 537MB
  ```
- ```
     ‘/dev/sda2  Ext4 ver 1.0 -not mounted, Linux Filesystem
  ```
- ```
     ‘/dev/sda3  LUKS Encryption ver 2 – Locked, Linux Filesystem
  ```
- fdisk -l shows same info as disks program
- cryptsetup -v open --type=luks2 /dev/sda3 ghs, No usable token is available.
- cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3

**LUKS header information**

- Version:        2
- Epoch:          3
- Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
- Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
- UUID:           51459cec-1774-491a-a8b2-0c4c88351cc1
- Label:          (no label)
- Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
- Flags:          (no flags)
- 
- Data segments:
- ```
  0: crypt
  ```
- ```
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
  ```
- ```
    length: (whole device)
  ```
- ```
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
  ```
- ```
    sector: 512 [bytes]
  ```
- 
- Keyslots:
- ```
  0: luks2
  ```
- ```
    Key:        512 bits
  ```
- ```
    Priority:   normal
  ```
- ```
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
  ```
- ```
    Cipher key: 512 bits
  ```
- ```
    PBKDF:      argon2i
  ```
- ```
    Time cost:  6
  ```
- ```
    Memory:     1048576
  ```
- ```
    Threads:    4
  ```
- ```
    Salt:       5a 7c 75 fb 9f 9d f0 c0 2d 77 d2 cc d5 20 3f cc
  ```
- ```
                88 35 0b f9 63 5c a9 8a 39 44 08 4b e1 aa e3 d2
  ```
- ```
    AF stripes: 4000
  ```
- ```
    AF hash:    sha256
  ```
- ```
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
  ```
- ```
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
  ```
- ```
    Digest ID:  0
  ```
- Tokens:
- Digests:
- ```
  0: pbkdf2
  ```
- ```
    Hash:       sha256
  ```
- ```
    Iterations: 131863
  ```
- ```
    Salt:       28 00 57 e8 a6 5c d9 ba 29 5a 65 17 5b 0b 6e 59
  ```
- ```
                2a 60 fe 07 21 c5 41 79 34 a2 79 ae 84 d9 1e 27
  ```
- ```
    Digest:     f9 14 4d 3c 31 80 44 29 f3 bb e1 74 90 84 7f 9d
  ```
- ```
                72 44 fe 8d 38 1f 03 b8 a3 e2 e9 b8 15 40 a3 a8 "
  ```
- 
- 

**QUESTIONS:**

- What are the methods and commands to mount an encrypted disc on an Ubuntu 22.04 USB Live USB system ?
- Is there any luksDump information that might indicate a hardware or software problem ?
- Is it possible that the LUKS password was changed or LUKS system files modified before I rebooted  ?  (I understand this would require sudo priviledges)
- Is there any discernable changes on modified LUKS system files that are checkable for changes before I reboot ?
- How can you tell if the LUKS passphrases have changed ?

  ```
                          ----====----
  ```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Have you upgraded to 22.04 or are you thinking about it?

Comment: I was planning on upgrading to 22.04 but have not been able to.